# AirPort Express extending AirPort Extreme wireless network: can I use WEP and WPA2 Personal?

Tags: network, airport, wifi

I have an AirPort Extreme home network that is extended with an AirPort Express.  Because some legacy devices within the household do not support WPA/WPA2 Personal, I would like to keep my AirPort Extreme network secured with WPA2 while allowing devices that can connect to the AirPort Express to connect via WEP.  Is this possible? (knowing in advance would certainly help, as I do not want to mess up the current configuration for the AirPort Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can save you current configuration in Airport Utility.

Then you have two options:
1. If your Extreme support guest network then just set it up as WEP and extend it with Express.
2. Or connect Express with ethernet to Extreme(i.e. just use it as gateway to internet) and setup WEP network on Express.

Comment: Your first option, the guest network with WEP, was the closest I could find to a solution; although Guest Network Security in AirPort Utility only allows for WPA/WPA2 Personal, I decided to make the main network WEP (Transitional Security Network) so that legacy devices could connect with WEP while newer devices could connect with WPA/WPA2. Could WEP (TSN) pose a security risk, or is it better than standard WEP?

Comment: It's ok. It means that if device support WPA it will try to authenticate as WPA and if not then WEP. If you have troubles though try to choose just WEP (you probably need to press alt/optn while selecting encryption method). TSN mode is definitely better as it probably make less packets in open air that are easily decoded (which WEP encrypted packets are)

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly not a full answer.  But I am going to bet that your final method is going to involve having your airport Extreme serve up two separate networks (you can configure it to serve up the 5GHZ band as a fully separate wireless network.)   But, this has the obvious disadvantage that that network will not be repeated on all the airport Expresses.